# Make jQuery UI draggable element only draggable in down direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Fixing a jQuery UI draggable element to an axis is pretty straightforward. You just set the axis option, but that still allows for two directions of dragging.

How can one limit the dragging to only one direction ( down )?

`$('.settings').draggable({axis:'y'});` makes `.settings` draggable up and down, but how can I get it to only work in the downwards direction?

Comment: Here's one that goes UP only:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619895/restricting-jquery-ui-draggable-to-drag-up-only-within-a-given-area

Comment: @DevlshOne That code doesn't make sense. His implementation of draggable doesn't do anything to block downwards drag, but it does block downwards drag?

Comment: are you looking at the question or the accepted answer? His code is actually quite brilliant. It's checking to see if the draggable is getting farther from the `top` of the DOM and then rejects that movement if it is. You just need to implement the same thing but relative to the `bottom` of the DOM.

Comment: @DevlshOne I don't see what you are talking about. Can you post an answer with the code that you are talking about.

Comment: I posted the link to the question that contains the code.. you want me to copy and paste it to the answer area? Sorry, I'm not going to do all your work for you, it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @DevlshOne No, I can't find the code you are talking about. The one that checks if it is getting farther from the top. I see the `.draggable({});` function with all the options and above it the comment `// drag Up, but not down`. But nothing about the top value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#repel').mousemove(function () {
    var z = $(window).scrollTop();
    var o = $('#repel').offset().top;
    var h = $('#repel').height();
        $("#containment-wrapper").css({
            top:  o + h -2000
        });
    if (z < 10) {
        $("#containment-wrapper").css({
            top: -850
        });
    } else {
        $("#containment-wrapper").css({
            top:  o + h -2000
        });
    }
});
```